# Find out which map tiles are visible in Google Maps for Android v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to find out which tiles are currently visible in Google Maps for Android v2. I tried to use a `TileProvider`, its `getTile(int x, int y, int zoom)` method is called whenever a new tile becomes visible. That's sufficient to my needs I guess but a set of currently visible tiles would be even better, is that possible?

Comment: As far as I know the TileProvider does that for you by only calling the getTile method for the tiles that it needs.

Comment: I don't get it. What else do you want?

Comment: The set of currently visible tiles.

Comment: Get the current zoom level and the northeast and southwest lat/lng of the visible screen, and back calculate the appropriate tiles from there: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Java

Answer (score 1):

It's doable with `TileProvider` after all, it's simple:

1. Add the `TileOverlay`.
2. In the `TileProvider`, record which tiles are requested.
3. Remove the `TileOverlay`. The tiles recorded in step 2 are the currently visible tiles.